# How to delete multiple rows, rather than one row at a time

Tags: excel, vba

In this code the rows are being deleted one by one, not all at the same time.

For every row I need to press the button again and again.

```
Sub Clean()
    disprow = 7
    Range("a" & disprow).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("a" & disprow).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: That code isn't deleting any rows.  All it is doing is clearing the contents of some cells.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to delete rows without any msg:

```
    Function jkjDeleteRowsWithoutMsg()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Rows("4:8").Delete 'you may change row index
    End Function
```